# Direction of compass needle nearby an electric wire

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, induction

Let through a straight wire flow an electric current. Using a compass needle how the needles tip will be directed to the wire? What happens when we switch the current direction and approach the needle again to the wire?

To get a source will be nice, but nicer it will be to get an answer from experiment which unfortunately  I didn't in the past and not able to do at the moment.

Comment: A [Google image search will find you pictures illustrating this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=straight+wire+compass&tbm=isch)

Comment: @john rennie Yes, [this](http://www.trincoll.edu/~cgeiss/stuff/the%20rocky%20road/ch_1/ch1_p1.htm) is ok. Does this is opposite to your answer about symmetry in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131920/asymmetry-in-magnetic-field-direction-of-an-electric-wire) question? For me the needles direction change if you change the current is pure asymmetric. Without experiment and derived therefrom rules you can't predict the result.

Comment: Yes, as already pointed out to you in your other question, the direction arises from a rule/convention. It can go one of two ways and we make a decision that the universe will obey a right-handed convention when we evaluate a vector product.

Comment: @RobJeffries Could you write this down as an answer in the older question, please.

Comment: I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt my description can be improved other than with a picture.

[image: Direction of a compass needle caused by a flow of current]

Now the interesting thing here is that *I* do not know which way the current is flowing, because I do not know which way the compass needles are colour-coded. I *guess* that the red represents the north pole. I do know that if the current flow is reversed then the needles will swap direction.

It really doesn't greatly matter. There is a defined direction and it is a convention that arises from the definition of vector product, the definition of conventional current flow and the sign convention in Ampere's law relating the curl of the B-field to the current density.