# How are (semi-) static fields treated quantum-mechanically?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

I am trying to understand a seemingly paradoxical assertion in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/171984/73762) which argues that the magnetic field of an inductor corresponds to virtual photons because there is no net momentum associated with the field. At least that logic is at odds with the treatment of trapped (nonstatical) fields such as in an optical resonator, where one can have nonzero net momentum yet considers it to be quantized as real photons.

The only logically consistent approach I have yet found is that only the forces classically described as mediated by a static field correspond to virtual photons, but that the energy stored in these fields must at least partially correspond to real photons, considering that, in creating or destroying the field, a small amount of the energy can leak out into the vacuum (accidental antenna effect). But I do not have enough information against which to test my current understanding to be satisfied of its correctness. Also, there is doubt stemming from the (unexplained) assertion in the linked question.

What is the correct way to describe e.g. the fields generated by an inductor quantum-mechanically?